# How can I implement a wildcard/catch all vhost

Tags: apache-2.4

What is the best way to implement a wildcard vhost using Apache in Debian so any folder I put in the /var/www/ folder will work like such

/var/www/abc
will automatically point to abc.local

/var/www/wp
will automatically point to wp.local

/var/www/test
will automatically point to test.local

I think the only thing I would have to do is manually edit the /etc/hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

In general, in Apache your first host is the one that will get displayed as default if no [ServerName](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#servername) or [ServerAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#serveralias).

May distros include a **000-default.conf** that becomes the default vhost.

Now, for your particular needs, Looks like you're setting up a dev environment. You can use DNSMasq and apache to automagically resolve .local to localhost and tell apache to look for it under a particular directory:

```
wp.local -> /var/www/wp
something.local -> /var/www/something
```

In **dnsmasq.conf**:

```
# catch .local
address=/.local/127.0.0.1
```

In apache:

```
<Directory "/var/www/">
  AllowOverride All
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost.local
  ServerAlias *.local
  UseCanonicalName off
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/
</VirtualHost>
```

See [this](http://alexking.org/blog/2015/04/20/dev-app-dnsmasq) post for further reference. He's using OS X but should work for any *nix distribution.